# Persist Data with DotNetRdf and Virtuoso Manager

Tags: virtuoso, dotnetrdf

I tried following the `dotnetrdf` [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide/Working%20with%20Graphs) to store data in a [Virtuoso Server](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).

Here is what I do:

```
public void LoadGraph()
{
    //Create our Storage Provider - this example uses Virtuoso Universal Server
    VirtuosoManager virtuoso = new VirtuosoManager("creativeartefact.org", 1111, "DB", "user", "password");

    //Load the Graph into an ordinary graph instance first
    Graph g = new Graph();
    virtuoso.LoadGraph(g, new Uri("http://creativeartefact.org/"));

    //Then place the Graph into a wrapper
    StoreGraphPersistenceWrapper wrapper = new StoreGraphPersistenceWrapper(virtuoso, g);

    //Now make changes to this Graph as desired...
    g.Assert(g.CreateUriNode(new Uri("http://creativeartefact.org/testB/123")), g.CreateUriNode("rdf:Type"), g.CreateUriNode(new Uri("http://creativeartefact.org/ontology/Artist")));
    wrapper.Flush(); // mandatory, but doesn't help either

    //Remember to call Dispose() to ensure changes get persisted when you are done
    wrapper.Dispose();
}
```

But - no data is saved and no exception is thrown. After inserting the triple, the triple count is raised by 1 as expected, but it doesn't make it's way into the database. The triple count is back to the old value when I rerun the code. The user account has `write` permissions.

Any idea what I am missing?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not fully reading the doc you're following.

> The easiest way to save a Graph to a Triple Store is to use the `SaveGraph()` method of an `IStorageProvider` implementation, see [Triple Store Integration](https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide/Triple%20Store%20Integration) for more details.

Comment: Well, as far as I understand it, this is an *alternative* way of storing changes and the example explicitily states "call Dispose() to ensure changes get persisted" - which I understand as "changes will be stored in the Triple Store". What else would be the "StoreGraphPersistanceWrapper" made for? But anyway - with the virtuoso.SaveGraph(g) command the change is stored in the Triple Store without the StoreGraphPersistanceWrapper - so thanks for the solution!