# Updating a Virtuoso graph with dotnetrdf

Tags: c#, virtuoso, dotnetrdf

After struggling with `dotnetrdf` and [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) to [save my graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980735/persist-data-with-dotnetrdf-and-virtuoso-manager), I try to update the graph with my changes. Again, I followed the [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide/Triple%20Store%20Integration) in section *`UpdateGraph()`*, and created the following code:

```
// and store the graph
if (_virtuoso.UpdateSupported)
    _virtuoso.UpdateGraph(insertGraph.BaseUri, insertGraph.Triples, null);
else
    log.Add("Updating not supported. Changes not stored");
```

The `insertGraph` is the Graph that contains my additions. I checked that `BaseUri` has the correct value and `insertGraph.Triples` contains my new Triples. `_virtuoso` is an instance of `VirtuosoManager`, with which I am able to `LoadGraph` and `SaveGraph`.

The code doesn't raise any exception, but still - no triple is inserted in the Virtuoso store. Any idea, what might be the problem or how I might get more information about the problem?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Comment: I tried the asynchroneous operation, with the same result. WasSuccessful is true, but still no updated Triples in the store ...

Comment: You might try reaching out directly to [the dotnetrdf folks](https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/Support), particularly via the [dotnetrdf-support mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/dotnetrdf-support).

Comment: The mailing list was closed some month ago. On Github they suggest to ask questions here at StackOverflow (https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/Support). Lets see ... :)

Comment: In that case... rather than [the old doc on Bitbucket, last updated 2013-02-20](https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide/Triple%20Store%20Integration), you might look to [the current doc on GitHub, last updated 2016-06-20](https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide-Triple-Store-Integration)…

Comment: Yes, but that's the same - they even copied the missnamed variable (declared as 'manager' used as 'virtuoso') ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was to call the Dispose method on the Virtuoso Manager. Only this forces the updates to be stored.

```
VirtuosoManager virtuosoManager = new VirtuosoManager(Configuration.VirtuosoServerName, Configuration.VirtuosoServerPort, VirtuosoManager.DefaultDB, User, Password);
virtuosoManager.UpdateGraph(graphUri, TriplesToAdd, TriplesToRemove);

// NECESSARY!! Otherwise, the changes won't be commited!      
virtuosoManager.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you arriving at the conclusion that no triples are being inserted? Have you put the Virtuoso Server in foreground debug mode which will display any issues that might have arisen during the execution of your code.

You can use the following to test if your data was loaded:

SELECT COUNT (*) WHERE {GRAPH ?g {?s a ?o}}

You can use the following to determine the named graph hosting your data within Virtuoso's RDF Quad Storage realm:

SELECT DISTINCT ?g WHERE {GRAPH ?g {?s a ?o}}